# Perguntas sobre como fraudar sistemas

Tags: debate, perguntas

Em alguns casos, mesmo sendo uma pergunta dentro do escopo de programação, o que devemos fazer com aquelas que a intenção é fraudar algum sistema?

Posso estar enganado, mas no exemplo que vi mais recente, **[nesta pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/52804/4337)** a intenção é fraudar o *AdSense*, proporcionando cliques automáticos nos banners de publicidade.

É claro que não devemos incentivar isso, mas simplesmente fechamos? Alertamos o usuário através de comentários? Direcionamos para outro lugar? Eu mesmo apenas comentei alertando que é contra a política, mas pergunto aqui porque será se apenas fechar a pergunta, o usuário não volta a perguntar?

Comment: Também já tive essa dúvida... Não sei se não foi discutida já aqui, mas fica o +1.

Comment: Relacionado: [O que fazer com perguntas com problemas de natureza ética?](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/1966/3117)

Comment: Eu acho a questão do autor válida, ele tem uma dúvida relacionada a programação, independente das intenções dele, a gente não sabe se ele tem interesse em fraudar ou testar as vulnerabilidades do adsense. Não acho que cabe ao stackoverflow julgar as intenções do usuário, não vejo motivos para fechar, mas quem pensar o contrário pode dar seu voto negativo.

Comment: Chega a ser irônico que o código da pergunta tem uma mensagem de "direitos reservados" do script.

Comment: Complementando, eu não tenho certeza sobre as intenções dele, mas de qualquer modo vai mesmo contra a política do Google. Quem sabe disso tem o dever de alertar, seja em comentário ou resposta. Nada impede de responder também a dúvida técnica, feito o alerta. Não acho que seja o caso de fechar a pergunta.

Comment: Tenho sérias duvidas sobre o que foi interpretado da questão...

Comment: Acho válidas tanto a pergunta aqui do meta, e a pergunta em questão. O que me surpreende é o ânimo do pessoal em votar negativamente numa pergunta perfeitamente dentro de todos os critérios do site, enquanto temos que engolir tanta porcaria no site por "forças superiores". Me parece que o site está cada vez mais "assistencialista" e menos técnico. E o pior, a resposta mais votada sequer é uma resposta ao que foi perguntado.

Comment: @Bacco, acho que houve um efeito manada muito forte nessa questão. Isso já se ocorreu com outras, mas essa foi levada para o lado antiético e repercutiu muito mal.

Answer (score 22):

A não ser que a pergunta seja descaradamente maliciosa, o melhor nesses casos é orientar o usuário e explicar que aquilo não deve ser feito, ainda que fosse possível.

Muita gente tenta burlar o funcionamento de serviços online violando as regras de uso simplesmente tentando cumprir ordens do patrão. Já vi muito disso com respeito aos web services da Receita Federal.

Certa vez um gerente, até bem intencionado, me questionou se não tinha um jeito de automatizar o preenchimento dos captchas de um determinado site. Ele não havia entendido que único propósito deles era justamente evitar a automação do acesso.

Comment: Pois é. Eu não acho que exista uma solução pra esses problemas éticos/morais no site que não envolva "tatear no escuro" até a hora que for desconfortável demais. Cada caso sempre será um caso. Não permitir qualquer pergunta assim é inaplicável, insustentável e exerce uma carga desconselhável à curiosidade comum. Ao mesmo tempo, achar que o site não deve se meter a julgar valores éticos ou morais é abrir margem para conteúdo com os quais a maioria de nós se sentiria desconfortável (o paradoxo do Reddit). Acho que cada caso vai ser sempre um caso.

Comment: Passei pelo mesmo problema. Tivemos que suspender a raspagem dos dados, em contrapartida, um serviço foi criado e tudo se resolveu.

Answer (score 14):

*Reli a questão e tenho sérias dúvidas sobre a 'má fé' do AP.*

> Tem como dar um .click automático em uma propaganda do google adsense [...] Ao clicar na div ***#teste*** ele de um click na propaganda e abra a página de publicidade do adsense

Acho que a confusão se deu pelo termo `click automático`.

Minha interpretação nesse momento foi de que ele precisa ter uma `DIV#TESTE` em qualquer posição da tela, e quando este elemento for clicado, será aberto o anúncio do *adsense*.

Já vi blogs com alinhamento central e quando você clica nos cantos, uma publicidade se abre, creio que seja esse princípio que o AP esteja querendo.

---

Não que não seja uma prática errada, mas sendo o caso, creio que anula a **má fé em torno dos cliques automatizados.**

Vamos dissertar :)

Comment: Concordo, dentro dessa perspectiva eu não vejo má fé do AP, não dá pra sair julgando apenas por ele buscar uma forma do usuário abrir o adsense a partir de um clique em uma DIV, afinal, que DIV é essa? Não conhecemos o que está sendo desenvolvendo de forma integral, o que seria ideal é que ele detalhasse melhor a finalidade da questão antes de condenarmos a questão ou algo do tipo. Não quero fazer papel de advogado do diabo, mas até que falte argumentos é bom debater.

Comment: @Orion, No primeiro momento eu 'condenei', mas não havia me manifestado ainda, depois eu revi a questão e acho que houve um equívoco na interpretação de `cliques automáticos`. *Acredito que houve um efeito manada*.

Answer (score 10):

Complementando a resposta do utluiz, eu acrescento que entender a finalidade para a qual o sistema está sendo burlado é importante. Por vezes alguns sistemas tem regras dracônicas e estúpidas das quais você só pode fazer o seu trabalho funcionar se algumas forem violadas (mesmo que o seu chefe não lhe peça isso e seja você que sugira isto a ele). Mesmo no caso do captcha, não é a toa que há muitas pessoas desenvolvendo programas para quebrar captchas. O famoso [JDownloader](http://jdownloader.org/) é um caso aonde isso ocorre.

Outras vezes, você gostaria de entender como burlar as regras dos seus sistemas antes que outras pessoas descubram como fazê-lo. Neste caso, este tipo de pergunta também é válido.

Mas no caso da pergunta no site principal que motivou a criação desta pergunta aqui no meta, o caso é provavelmente malícia e falta de ética descarada mesmo com a intenção de promover uma fraude. Se não for isso, é um caso de muita inocência mesmo. Então, a menos que o autor da pergunta dê uma boa justificativa do porquê ele quer ou precisa fazer isso, não acho que ele deva ser ajudado.

Apesar disso, mesmo assim postei uma resposta, pois acho que ela poderá ajudar alguma outra pessoa que veja a pergunta.