# Perguntas no SOPT com códigos que remetem a softwares maliciosos podem ser consideradas fora dos padrões da comunidade?

Tags: debate, comunidade

As vezes quando vejo algumas perguntas no so me pergunto qual o limite de assunto que se pode perguntar, como diz no próprio [guia](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour) do SOPT:

> Faça perguntas, obtenha respostas, sem distrações

Não vi nenhum termo de "comportamento de código" (Não achei uma palavra melhor para isso), então se uma pessoa posta uma pergunta e o código esta claramente relacionado a um trecho de código de um vírus ou semelhantes isso poderia ser classificado como comportamento inadequado? Por exemplo [esta pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/210721/criar-chave-no-registro-do-windows-sem-permiss%C3%A3o-em-c), não estou dizendo que ele esteja tentando fazer algo ilegal, mas como ele mesmo diz, ele quer adicionar uma chave de registro sem permissão para adicionar o programa dele as exclusões, e o caminho do registro indica o Windows Defender, um software com esse tipo de comportamento me lembra bastante um vírus.

Comment: Achei essas referências: [O que fazer com perguntas com problemas de natureza ética?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1966/70), [Perguntas sobre como fraudar sistemas](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2525/70) e [Pergunta com links maliciosos a respeito de segurança?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7080/70)